# skip_after_filter with if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I do `skip_after_filter` with an `if` statement?

```
skip_after_filter :intercom_rails_auto_include if current_account.expired?
```

I'm using Rails 4.0.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
skip_after_filter :intercom_rails_auto_include, if: :expired?

private 
def expired?
  current_account.expired?
end
```