# Test 'skip_after_action' method in application_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have in my application controller something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21766346/2747638) :

```
skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include, if: :current_staff_user?

private 

def current_staff_user?
  session[:staff_user_id]
end
```

I would like to know how I can test properly this method with rspec. I've check [the help](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller#specify-error-handling-in-<code>applicationcontroller</code>)

The only way I've found is this one :

```
  describe 'disable intercom when user is impersonate' do
    controller do
      skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include, if: :current_staff_user?

      def index
        user_is_admin?
      end
    end

    context 'when user is not impersonate' do
      subject { get(:index, {'bim': 50}) }

      before { expect(controller).to receive(:current_staff_user?).twice.and_return(false) }

      it { is_expected.to redirect_to root_path(locale: :en)}
    end

    context 'when user is not impersonate' do
      subject { get(:index, {'bim': 50}, {'staff_user_id': 50}) }

      before { expect(controller).to receive(:current_staff_user?).and_return(true) }

      it { is_expected.to redirect_to root_path(locale: :en) }
    end
  end
```

Any idea how to it differently without rewriting `skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include, if: :current_staff_user?` inside my test ?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to test the Application controller. I believe **you will need to use the Anonymous Controller** and put the filter in there just like your are doing with this block of code you have

```
controller do
  skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include, if: :current_staff_user?
  ...
end
```

I don't like it. **Really.** It's like writing code in a test ... to test that you wrote your `test code` correctly. But ... I believe using the AnonymousController does seem to be the consensus of what to do. Maybe someone will come up with a better way someday.

Comment: Yes @MilesStanfield you're completely right. Writing code in test was for me a code smell. Maybe the other way of doing it is to call a method from an other controller. ApplicationController will be called and then I can check method call.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the expectation to make it clear that it's been skipped. Otherwise your solution is close to as good as you can do.

```
expect(controller).to not_receive(:intercom_rails_auto_include)
```

Comment: I've tried something like `before { expect(controller).not_to receive(:intercom_rails_auto_include) }` but I get `Failure/Error: subject { get(:index, {'bim': 50}) } expected: 0 times with any arguments
           received: 1 time`

Comment: Sounds like a scope problem. You might need the counterpart to `expect(controller).to receive(:intercom_rails_auto_include)` in the other test to make sure the stub isn't leaking over. If it continues to fail it might well be being called, replace the method body of `intercom_rails_auto_include` with a `throw` and check your stack.